# Heroku postgresql database name

Tags: postgresql, heroku

This is the command I have to find the name of a heroku database:

```
$ heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL
```

I get a result similar to:

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL: postgres://wxjwilh:tKDSwUlfZ8Da@fr6-84-24-28-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com:52/d14grmkt
```

which part of this output is the database name I can use with the command:

```
$ heroku pg:reset <DATABASE>
```

I tried using the whole url but got an invalid argument error.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

hope everyone confuses with placeholder and constant.

Assume having a db with name *d6u5qhrlnbdfmp*. then it is NOT necessary to type

```
heroku pg:reset d6u5qhrlnbdfmp
```

Instead we can plainly type

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

the sample output

```
E:\git\stutzen>heroku pg:reset d6u5qhrlnbdfmp --app stutzen
 !    Unknown database: d6u5qhrlnbdfmp. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_
POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL

E:\git\stutzen>heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --app stutzen

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: stutzen
 !    To proceed, type "stutzen" or re-run this command with --confirm stutzen


> stutzen
Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL (DATABASE_URL)... done
```

Comment: all `heroku pg:*` commands (including those in [pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) can use any of the following as a DB indicator: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL`, `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY`, `NAVY`. In case `NAVY` is also your primary `DATABASE_URL`, you can use that too.

Answer (score 23):

URL consists of the following parts:

```
scheme://username:password@host:port/database
```

So, in your case DB name is `d14grmkt`.

Answer (score 13):

I had a hard time to reset my database on Heroku. I post this, because I think it's the most straightforward solution. To find out the database name cd to your application folder and type:

```
heroku pg:info
```

Output will be something like

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
#other stuff
```

To reset the database type:

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
```

you have to confirm with your application name.

Comment: Came here from googling trying to find something like `heroku pg:info` to list my database name. Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

While using the command:

`$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE`

It will tell you the available database name like this:

`!    Unknown database: DATABASE_URL. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL, SHARED_DATABASE`

so try the options it gave like this

`$ heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER_URL`

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but if you need the db name, for example to add it as an addon to another instance, you run

```
heroku addons
```

In the list you will see your postgres addon, in the 'Add-on' column is the name of the db app that is attached

Answer (score 0):

**NOT MENTIONED IN THE HEROKU WEBSITE DOCUMENTATION:**

```
 heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --version=12 --app "APPNAME" --name "APPNAME-database"
```

**--app** : Specify the heroku app you want to add the database too. Really good if you have more than one heroku app.

**--name** : The name you would like to give your database. I like to take my application name and postfix it with "database" as a nice convention. Better than whatever randomly generated name you'll get.

**APPNAME**: A placeholder for whatever your application name is.