# How to set DateStyle for Heroku Postgress to DMY?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am staging a newly build web application on Heroku. As we are in Asia, all our date format is DMY. However Heroku Postgres is in MDY.

After researching, I thought this post [Heroku Postgresql SET datestyle To european](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089687/heroku-postgresql-set-datestyle-to-european) is the solution.

```
in heroku pg:psql

ALTER DATABASE database_name SET datestyle TO 'ISO, european';
```

It does not work. At this point, I am stuck on what else I can do to change date format.

For info, I use database_name from the DATABASE_URL in the

```
heroku pg:credentials:url

Connection URL:
postgres://user:pasword@host:port/**database_name**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `datestyle` to `'GERMAN, DMY'` for that. Also, don't forget that changes made wil `ALTER DATABASE` only apply to new database sessions.